# ng-options predefined option Object

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

Have a look at my example
http://plnkr.co/edit/21ewxVIaRm4IHyF3TgoD?p=preview

I need the option object to be stored as ng-model so i use for ng-options `ng-options="m as m.name for m in list"`

However, if i set ng-model manually as the object it does not select the correct option in the dropdown list by default. It stores the data correctly, but it only pre-selects an option if use this expression `ng-options="m.name as m.name for m in list"` but this stores a string on the model instead of the options object.

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Goal:

- set ng-model to the default option object and have it be automatically selected in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9m8W70c43O58et1OmoYm?p=preview).

For the version you are using (1.0.8), you would have to resolve the object using a loop:

```
$scope.selected = {
    name:"Something"
  }

  $scope.setSelected = function() {

    angular.forEach($scope.list, function(item) {

      if (item.name == $scope.selected.name) {

        $scope.selected = item;
      }
    })
  }

  $scope.setSelected();
```

More recent versions, have `track by` syntax supported in the `ng-options`.  So you could write:

```
ng-options="m.name for m in list track by m.name"
```

And this would set the object that matches the predicate.

Comment: Awesome, worked flawlessly. Thank you!
Upgraded using `bower install angular#1.2.0-rc.3` seamless.

Answer (score 0):

As Davin Tryon has already mentioned, using track by is the correct way of doing it, however, I see some people using track by and 'as' in the same ng-options string, which will not work. using track by should also cater the need of using 'as'